# Sending IRP_MJ_SYSTEM_CONTROL request from user-mode

Tags: c++, driver, wmi, hardware, wdk

I have Windows kernel-mode driver and user-mode DLL as an interlayer between driver and GUI application.

I send IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL requests from user-mode DLL to driver using [DeviceIoControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/aa363216(v=vs.85).aspx) function and it works well.

But I'd like to send IRP_MJ_SYSTEM_CONTROL requests from user-mode as well. I have pnp.c module in my driver source code with implementing [DispatchSystemControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543412(v=vs.85).aspx) routine that handles such IRPs as IRP_MN_START_DEVICE, IRP_MN_START_DEVICE, IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE and some other.

I can see that this handlers works well for example IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE handler is called any time when I remove my device.

But I'd like to know is there any way to send IRP_MJ_SYSTEM_CONTROL requests from user-mode using some function for example in the same way as I send IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL using DeviceIoControl

Answer (score 0):

IRP_MJ_SYSTEM_CONTROL request is sent by the kernel mode driver of WMI. For more details, see [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550813(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @chaika_sv if this is helpful to you, please mark this post as `Answered` for others' benefits